# Is there an option in Prometheus to disable scraping a specific endpoint?

Tags: prometheus, screen-scraping, disable

In order to minimize the load on Prometheus Federation, I am trying to disable scraping of specific metrics. Please let me know if we have such options or any other alternative.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/):

> At least one `match[]` URL parameter must be specified to select the series to expose. Each `match[]` argument needs to specify an instant vector selector like `up` or `{job="api-server"}`. If multiple `match[]` parameters are provided, the union of all matched series is selected.

In other words, by using `match[]` you can explicitly say which metrics you want to federate.

```yaml
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'federate'
    scrape_interval: 15s

    honor_labels: true
    metrics_path: '/federate'

    params:
      'match[]':
        # all metrics with label job == "prometheus"
        - '{job="prometheus"}'
        # plus all metrics with label foo == "bar" where instance != "example.com"
        - '{foo="bar", instance!="example.com"}'         
        # and so on

    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - 'source-prometheus-1:9090'
        - 'source-prometheus-2:9090'
        - 'source-prometheus-3:9090'
```